# Codeigniter / Nginx Leverage browser caching on page speed

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, nginx

Currently working on steps to improve SEO following a guide that was given to me and it recommends working on page speed and to use goggle page speed insights, so far its been helpful but I've got the one error bugging about leverage browser caching on 3 items

```
http://c-elec.co.uk/img/part_p_logo.gif (expiration not specified)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js (30 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

I'm using Nginx hosted on a server, i checked the config file for the project and it contains caching rules on jpg|png|css|js|gif etc and is set to 14 days, I've asked the admin to double check and he said all the configs contain this rule.

is it Google messing around or is there something missing as overtime i check this is the flag that pops up and the perfectionist in me wants to fix it before moving on.